# R: How to build a SQL using table, column and schema names from a dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, apply, lapply

I want to run the same SQL on a stack of tables, columns and db schemata. I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
schema <- c('schema_1','schema_1','schema_1', 'schema_2', 'schema_2')
table <- c('table_1','table_1','table_2', 'table_3', 'table_3')
column <- c('A','B','V','X','Y')
df <- data.frame(schema, table, column)
```

I want to run a simple SQL with the first rows of a column like this, on all rows of the df:

library(postGIStools)

```
get_postgis_query(con_ent_gis, "select column from schema.table LIMIT 6")
```

As far I understand I could write something similar to

```
get_postgis_query(con_ent_gis, "select df$column[i] from df$schema[i].df$table[i] LIMIT 6")
```

in a for Loop, wright? Or does any package or function as apply, lapply.. do something similar, without the need of a Loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `paste` (or its non-space wrapper, `paste0`) to build a vector of SQL statements since all objects are same length. Then, pass vector into `lapply` for iterative query calls for a list of returned objects.

```
# BUILD VECTOR OF SQL STATEMENTS
sqls <- paste0("select ", df$column, " from ", df$schema, ".", df$table, " LIMIT 6")
sqls    
# [1] "select A from schema_1.table_1 LIMIT 6"
# [2] "select B from schema_1.table_1 LIMIT 6"
# [3] "select V from schema_1.table_2 LIMIT 6"
# [4] "select X from schema_2.table_3 LIMIT 6"
# [5] "select Y from schema_2.table_3 LIMIT 6"

# ITERATIVELY RUN EACH QUERY TO RETURN LIST OF OBJECTS
data_list <- lapply(sqls, function(s) get_postgis_query(con_ent_gis, s))
```